# Is there a way to get plot a ggplot object without having to save it into memory?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am working on shiny app and I have slight problem. There is a graph that I want to put at several places on my app.

The graph is created by a funtion who returns a ggplot object. I use the usual way of plotting the graph which is basically calling the object inside the renderPlot function.

Here is the problem. Some graphs are too big and plotting them takes considerable time. So using the usual way of plotting takes too much unnecessary time, what I would like to do is to "plot" the ggplot object in my function before passing it on to shiny.

In theory, I could save the ggplot to a image file and then import the file but that seems like too much unnecessary work.